# Solve analytically integral $\int\frac{y^4}{\sqrt{(1-y^2)(y^2-r^2)}}dy$

Tags: integration, roots

I tried to solving $\int\frac{y^4}{\sqrt{(1-y^2)(y^2-r^2)}}dy$  analytically, someone has any ideas?

Comment: *Mathematica* gives:  $$\frac{-\sqrt{-\frac{1}{r^2}} y \left(y^2-1\right) (r-y) (r+y)+i \sqrt{1-y^2}
   \sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{r^2}} \left(2 \left(r^2+1\right) E\left(i \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{-\frac{1}{r^2}} y\right)|r^2\right)-\left(r^2+2\right) F\left(i \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{-\frac{1}{r^2}} y\right)|r^2\right)\right)}{3 \sqrt{-\frac{1}{r^2}}
   \sqrt{\left(y^2-1\right) (r-y) (r+y)}}$$

Comment: Square root of a quartic, you expect this to be an elliptic integral.  As Mathematica found.

Comment: I got a similar answer in wolfram, however i like to solve analytically.. for try to get other expression

Comment: The fact that *Mathematica* gives this as the answer means you'll have to derive *this* answer by hand.  Do you really think that is worth your time?  How many algebra errors do you think you'll make while you try?  If you're "certain" you made no mistakes but that your answer differs from *Mathematica*, what will you do?

Comment: That _is_ the analytical solution; it is not expressible in terms of the standard elementary functions, only in terms of the elliptic integrals. If the interval of integration is $[0,1]$ then [further simplifications are possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type).

Comment: I agree with your comments, but I need with  the interval of integration  [r,1] and and I don't know how to leave this expression since I have to get a real value.

Comment: You can probably get rid of the imaginaries in the expression yourself; for example $i\sinh^{-1}\sqrt{-(y/r)^2}=\sin^{-1}(y/r)$. Otherwise this may be the simplest expression you could hope for... There are some fast converging algorithms for computing elliptic integrals which could be useful depending on what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume $0 < r < 1$
$$I(y)=\int\frac{y^4}{\sqrt{(1-y^2)(y^2-r^2)}}dy$$
$$I(y)=-\frac{1}{3} y \sqrt{\left(1-y^2\right) (y^2-r^2)}+\frac{1}{3} i
   \left(\left(r^2+2\right) F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{r}\right)|r^2\right)-2
   \left(r^2+1\right) E\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{r}\right)|r^2\right)\right)$$ This makes
$$J(r)=\int_r^1 \frac{y^4}{\sqrt{(1-y^2)(y^2-r^2)}}dy=$$
$$\frac{i}{3}  \left(\frac{\left(r^2+2\right)}{r} \left(K\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)-r
   K\left(r^2\right)\right)+2 \left(r^2+1\right)\left( E\left(r^2\right)- E\left(\csc ^{-1}(r)|r^2\right)\right)\right)$$ which, for sure,is a real $(\frac 23 \leq J(r) \leq \frac \pi 2)$.

Comment: one thing more, how I can introduce in Mathematica the limit  0 < r < 1 to get  an answer like this.